# Cannot get lines() function to change individual color of lines added

Tags: r

I am attempting to change the colors of lines in a chi-squared distribution that is being added on to a normal distribution curve. The lines only come up as one specific color, not all three that I want.

This is the current code I am using. The normal distribution curve works as it should. But all chi-squared values come up in the same color. I want each individual curve to be a specific color. I think it might have something to do with my for loop as I'm not exactly sure how to use them. The code was given to me as fill in the blank.

```
x <- seq(-4, 45, length=500)         # x values
dist.x <- dnorm(x, mean = 20, sd = 5)    # Returns CDF of normal distribution with mean 20 and sd 5.

degf <- c(4,10, 20)             # Set up the three degree of freedoms
colors <- c("green","red", "blue", "black")  # Set up the four colors 
labels <- c("df=4", "df=10","df=20",  "normal")       # Label the plots

plot(dist.x, col = colors[4], type="l", lty=2, lwd=2, xlab="x value",
  ylab="Density", main="Comparison of Normal and Chi-Square Distributions")         # Plot normal density curve

for (i in x){
  lines(x, dchisq(x,degf[1:3]), lty=1, lwd=2, col= colors[1:3]) # Plot chi-square distribution curves
                                   # dchisq() returns CDF of chi-square distribution
                                   # col= set up colors for the chi-square distributions
}

legend("topright", inset=0.01, title="Distributions",       # Set up the title of legend
  labels, lwd=2, lty=c(1, 1, 1, 2), col=colors)  # Set up line types appearing in the legend
```

Comment: you should have `for (i in 1:3)` instead and change the `1:3`s in the loop to `i`